# How can I share LiveData between multiple ViewModels?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I've tried extracting the value into a base class and having the ViewModels extend it. When I do that, however, the Observer isn't sticking to the LiveData. For instance, when I have a parent class with LiveData:

```
class Base : ViewModel() { 
    private val _ data = MutableLiveData()
    val data: LiveData = _data

    fun someEvent(foo: Foo) { // update _data }
}

class Derived : Base()

class Derived1 : Base()
```

Then get one of those ViewModels and observe `data`:

```
class Frag : Fragment {
    onViewCreated() {
        // get Derived, ViewModelProviders.of ...etc
       derived.data.observe { // Doesn't observe changes }
    }
}
```

Calling `Base.someEvent(foo)` doesn't notify the LiveData in the Fragment.

I want to avoid getting a reference to both subclasses and invoking `someEvent` on each. One thing to note is that I'm using a single Activity approach and all ViewModels are Activity scoped.

Comment: The `// update _data` is kind of the critical piece of code. What exactly are you doing there?

Comment: Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56521969/how-to-share-an-instance-of-livedata-in-android-app/56521970#56521970

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Derived : Base()
```

and

```
class Derived1 : Base()
```

have their own instance of:

```
private val _ data = MutableLiveData()
val data: LiveData = _data
```

that means you need to

```
derived.data.observe { // do something }
derived1.data.observer { // do something }
derived.someEvent(someFoo)
derived1.someEvent(someFoo)
```

You are trying to achieve something in a wrong way.

Comment: I have a floating action button on multiple(but not all) fragments. It would be ideal to simply dispatch a single click listener with the current location to all relevant fragments instead of setting a click listener for each.

Comment: I don't understand can you explain that further?

Comment: My activity has multiple fragments and some have a FAB. When the FAB is clicked I want some contextual action to occur (will largely be screen dependant but there are other factors too). I feel that doing activity.fab.onclick() in each of those fragments would break encapsulation.

Comment: then delegate the onClick to the Fragments. I dont understand why you can't place the onClick logic inside the fragment.

Comment: So we cannot have abstracted LiveData's?