# How to share an instance of LiveData in android app?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

**Simple use case**

I am using **MVVM** architecture and [Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture) in my app.

After user logs in, I am fetching multiple network data and want to have access to it from different [ViewModels](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?gclid=Cj0KCQjw3PLnBRCpARIsAKaUbgtpvCpgpg3s10Ez6mR_Jrz9asWtjwooJw3EgbDsHzg_jdPqbhREdBMaArQ6EALw_wcB) attached to different **Activities** lifecycle.

I don't want to use [Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) in my app.

I have seen some question about sharing a **ViewModel** between **Activities** or using a [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) as static member, but I think most of the cases we need to access the same data in multiple screens.

I want to share a solution, but if there is better one or there is an issue with this, please post your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to have a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) **Repository**, which shares a **LiveData** between consumers (**ViewModels**).

```
class SharedLiveDataRepository(val dataSource: MyDataSource) {

    // This LiveData is shared across consumers
    private val result = MutableLiveData<Long>()

    fun loadData(): LiveData<Long> {
        if (result.value == null) {
            result.value = dataSource.getData()
        }
        return result
    }

}
```

If for some reason you would like to refresh the data, the `loadItem` method can look like this

```
  fun loadData(refresh: Boolean = false): LiveData<Long> {
        if (refresh == true) {
            result.value = null
        } 
        if (result.value == null) {
            result.value = dataSource.getData()
        }
        return result
    }
```

**Please Note:** For refreshing the data it is possible to see a glitch.

Imagine a scenario when there is transition between two activities and first one is observing the LiveData and the second one starting refreshing it.

I think the solution for the above issue is to do the refresh in first activity and then navigate to the next one.

Comment: This will work if `dataSource.getData()` is an instant operation, but otherwise the UI thread will be blocked.

Comment: Nice. But I would consider not to store the 'result' Livedata in the repository, but hold it in the ViewModel as a member. I guess you hold the result data already in your VM. So this will reduce redundant memory allocation. As you are sharing the ViewModels, it is not going to be cleared(), until you destroy the activity. Essentially the repository layer should only be used for data retrieval and not to hold any data.

Comment: @BadhrinathCanessane in that case for every `VM` which is attached to a new `Activity` will do a new API call, if I just return `dataSource.getData()`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. My answer is for using a single Activity with multiple fragments and to share the VM across fragments. But this link might help you. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/29